# Odd Error When creating kind of a pivot table (sql)

Tags: sql-server, select, case

I have Two tables:

table 1: MSVTransaction

table 2: [MonthlySalary]

I would like to create a pivot table comparing the amount for employees between the two tables:

```
  select 
      [MSV_EntitledIdNumber],
      [MS_Semel],
      sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (1) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as JanMSV,
      sum(case when [MS_Month] in (1) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as JanSML,
      sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (2) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as FebMSV,
      sum(case when [MS_Month] in (2) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as FebSML,
      sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (3) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as MarMSV,
      sum(case when [MS_Month] in (3) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as MarSML,
      sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (4) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as AprMSV,
      sum(case when [MS_Month] in (4) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as AprSML,
      sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (5) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as MayMSV,
      sum(case when [MS_Month] in (5) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as MaySML,
      sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (6) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as JunMSV,
      sum(case when [MS_Month] in (6) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as JunSML,
      sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (7) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as JulMSV,
      sum(case when [MS_Month] in (7) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as JulSML,
      sum(case when [MSV_Month] in (8) then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 end) as AugMSV,
      sum(case when [MS_Month] in (8) then [MS_Amount] else 0 end) as AugSML,
      sum(case when [MSV_Month] between 1 and 8 then [MSV_PaymentAmount] else 0 
    from [dbo].[MSVTransaction] as msv
    left join [dbo].[MonthlySalary] as SmlTbl on SmlTbl.[MS_InfoEmpNum] =
    msv.MSV_EntitledIdNumber And SmlTbl.MS_Month = msv.MSV_Month
    Where SmlTbl.[MS_MSF_Code] between 4 and 27 and 
    SmlTbl.[MS_Semel] = '666' And msv.[MSV_EntitledIdNumber]= 55555
    and msv.[MSV_MSVT_CodeID] not between 198 and 213
    group by [MSV_EntitledIdNumber],[MS_Semel]
```

When I run this I get:

```
MSV_EntitledIdNumber    MS_Semel         JanMSV JanSML  FebMSV  FebSML  MarMSV  MarSML  AprMSV  AprSML  MayMSV  MaySML          JunMSV  JunSML  JulMSV  JulSML  AugMSV  AugSML  
    55555             666       2000    2000    5000    5000    6000    6000    8000    8000    7000    7000                       80000    160000  15000   30000   14000   14000
```

I would like to pay your attention to:

```
JunMSV  JunSML  JulMSV  JulSML  where the amounts are diffrent between one and other.
```

Looks like the amount in monthlySalary got double ( 15K * 2 for July and 80K * 2 for june) - why? The original data is:

[MonthlySalary]

```
MS_InfoEmpNum   MS_Semel    MS_Month    MS_Amount
55555             666           1           2000
55555             666           2           5000
55555             666           3           6000
55555             666           4           8000
55555             666            5          7000
55555             666           6          80000
55555             666           7         15000
55555             666           8          14000
```

And MSVTransaction:

```
MSV_EntitledIdNumber    MSV_PaymentAmount   MSV_Month
55555                       2000                1
55555                       5000                2
55555                       6000                3
55555                       8000                4
55555                       7000                5
55555                       75000               6
55555                       5000                6
55555                       4000                7
55555                      11000                7
55555                      14000                8
```

Looks like the problem  occurred In the rows where there is two records and the code just summing twice but take the same amount.It should have been 20000 in July and 85K in June and in that case msv and sml fields are equal. Any help to fix it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate months in the `MSVTransaction` table.  Hence, the values are multiplied.  A good method to solve this is to aggregate before doing the join.  The `from` clause would look like:

```
from [dbo].[MSVTransaction] msv left join
     (select MSV_EntitledIdNumber, MS_Month, 
             sum(MSV_PaymentAmount) as MSV_PaymentAmount
      from [dbo].[MonthlySalary] SmlTbl
      group by msv.MSV_EntitledIdNumber, SmlTbl.MS_Month
    ) smlTbl
    on SmlTbl.[MS_InfoEmpNum] = msv.MSV_EntitledIdNumber And
       SmlTbl.MS_Month = msv.MSV_Month
```

Comment: Gordon, Thank's but I think some of the fields you wrote are not corret. The sum should be in MSVTransaction?